# Check if in an align* environment

Tags: math-mode, macros, align

I want to use different styles of matrices if TeX is in an `align*` environment or in a normal math environment. I already found a solution for checking if it is in math mode (`\ifmmode`) but not something to check if it is in an `align`. So far my code would look like this:

```
\newcommand\cvec[1]{
    \relax\ifmmode\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\else\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}\fi}
```

Or is there another simple command to do this?

Comment: In *any* math formula `\ifmmode` is true, so the false branch in your conditional will never be followed. Unfortunately, distinguishing between inline formulas and displayed ones requires `\mathchoice`. Don't use `align*` as a replacement for `equation*` (or `\[...\]`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd avoid such an approach. Matrices in inline formulas should be used very sparingly, because as soon as a `smallmatrix` has more than two rows, it will spoil the equidistance between baselines.

The `amsmath` package provides `\ifinalign@` and `\ifingather@`, so your aim might be accomplished by

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cvec[1]{%
  \relax
  \ifinalign@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \ifingather@
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  \fi
  {\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}%
  {\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)}%
}
\makeatother
```

but the `\cvec` macro will not work as expected in `equation` or `multline`. Note that `align` and `gather` should not be used as substitutes for `equation` (with or without `*` in all cases), but only for multiline displays.

The only correct way to ensure correct working of `\cvec` in all these cases is using `\mathchoice`:

```
\newcommand{\cvec}[1]{%
  \mathchoice{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
    {\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)}
    {\text{$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}
    {\text{$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}
}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\cvec}[1]{%
  \mathchoice{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
    {\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)}
    {\text{$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}
    {\text{$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}
}

\begin{document}
$\cvec{a\\b}$
\begin{align}
\cvec{a\\b}
\end{align}
\begin{gather}
\cvec{a\\b}
\end{gather}
\begin{equation}
\cvec{a\\b}
\end{equation}
\begin{multline}
x\\\cvec{a\\b}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Try with the definition above and you'll see that in equations 3 and 4 the output would be with a `smallmatrix`.

My suggestion is to define a macro with a `*`-variant, so the asterisk can easily been added or dropped.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cvec}{\@ifstar{\thomas@scvec}{\thomas@cvec}}
\newcommand{\thomas@scvec}[1]{%
  \text{$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}
\newcommand{\thomas@cvec}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
\makeatother
```

Alternatively, with `xparse`,

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\cvec}{ s m }{%
 \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\text{$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}}
   {\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}%
}
```

You'll use `\cvec*` for the inline mode and `\cvec` for the display mode. You can leave out `\text` if you don't plan to use `\cvec*` in sub/superscripts.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{align}
  \ifinalign@ true \else false \fi
\end{align}

\[
  \ifinalign@ true \else false \fi
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice, except that it would be helpful to point out that any references that require `\makeatletter` are best done only in command definitions.  having the `@` "live" in the body of a document can cause confusion, if not actual problems.