# Can't make Line-less Fraction

Tags: lyx, windows

I'm trying to make a line-less fraction to more accurately show vector coordinates. At least my teacher wants us to show them in brackets one above the other like a fraction, but without the fraction line as it isn't a fraction.

I'm using LyX and have been trying to look around on how to get this functionality. It seems that the macro is `\bfrac` but LyX doesn't know this macro or actually seem to have the ability to do this.

Anyone of you know, how I could solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried the plain-TeX macro `\atop`, e.g., `$ \left[ {a \atop b} \right]$`. Note the special syntax.

Comment: Huh, It was `\atop`. That's weird, I didn't see that anywhere in the toolbars ._. Thanks dude! If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: If you got `\bfrac` from http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=14773 (it is not in standard LaTeX nor `amsmath`) you will need to copy the `\newcommand` line into the LaTeX preamble and use an ERT I suppose.

Comment: See my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152208/4427

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may want to use the plain-TeX directive `\atop`. It uses so-called infix notation. If you end up using `\atop` a lot, you may want to create a LaTeX-style macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myatop[2]{\left[{{#1}\atop#2}\right]} % "wrapper macro"
\begin{document}

%% plain-TeX syntax
$ \left[ {u \atop v} \right]$, $\displaystyle \left[ {u \atop v} \right]$

\bigskip
%% LaTeX-type syntax
$ \myatop{u}{v}$, $\displaystyle \myatop{u}{v}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

here's another method, based on the `amsmath` command `\genfrac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\brkbinom}{\genfrac[]{0pt}{}}

\begin{document}
$\brkbinom{a}{b}$, $\displaystyle\brkbinom{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

this is actually essentially the same as this answer: 
 [Latex `\binom` with other types of brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228111/579).

Comment: Or `smallmatrix`? (Which doesn't scale, I know).